# Function to create processes in C

Tags: c, shell, fork, pipe

im trying to implement a shell using C.
I'm currently trying to deal with the pipes of the program with no luck yet. I was wondering how could i process a command such as

```
SHELL$: sort < txtFile | grep key
```

i parsed the command line so that i have sort < txtFile in one char* array, and grep key in another char* array

any help would be greatly appreciated.

this is the code i have so far:

PS: i didnt include the code that deals with the redirects

```
pid = fork();
if(pid == 0) 
{ 
    /* child process */
    if( PIPE_FLAG )
    {   
        close(c2p[0]);
        if(dup2(c2p[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1){
            perror("dup2() failed");
            exit(2);
        }
    }
    /* Execute command */
    execvp(cmd_args[0], cmd_args);
    perror("exec failed 1. ");          /* return only when exec fails */
    exit(-1);

} 
else if(pid > 0) 
{ 
    /* parent process */
    if(!async) 
        waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    else 
        printf("this is an async call\n");

    if(PIPE_FLAG)
    {
        close(c2p[1]);
        if(dup2(c2p[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1){
            perror("dup2() failed");
            exit(-1);
        }
        execvp(nxt_args[0], nxt_args);
        perror("exec failed 2. ");          
        exit(-1);
    }
} 
else 
{ 
    /* error occurred */
    perror("fork failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

this is my main:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv [])
{
  char commands[BUFSIZ];
  for(;;)
  {
    printf("MYSHELL$ ");
    if(fgets(commands, BUFSIZ, stdin) == NULL) 
    {
        perror("fgets failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    execute(commands) ;
  }

 return 0;
}
```

so after the call to the above command, my shell loop terminates.
How could i solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your problem is you exec() in the parent process too when piping. exec() replaces the current process with the new one, so when you call it in the parent, your shell is replaced, so the loop doesn't even exist anymore.

For every exec() in your shell, you should fork() first, to ensure that the parent shell process remains alive.

Comment: Okay, so i shouldnt run exec in the parent, only in the child... so how could i run that other exec in the child?

Comment: You don't.  You have more than 1 child - sort & grep - and you need to pipe them together.

Comment: @Duck so i need to create another process? where, and how should i create this new process?

Comment: Yeah, put the code inside your if(PIPE_FLAG) as the child of another fork(). Play with this kind of thing: `if(pipe_flag) if(fork() == 0) { close() dup2() exec() }`. This way, the parent shell remains running as both new processes are made.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe thanks for your reply, so i should create that other process within the 'if(pid == 0) and fork here in the child' ?

Comment: In the shell, always have the parent process fork. so for the first one, you `if(fork() == 0) { exec(prog1); } else { /*parent, fork again to start the second process */ if(fork() == 0) { exec(program_2); } else { /* still in the parent, return and/or wait pid so your loop can continue */ }`

Comment: Better to do it in a loop because you can't anticipate how many children you will need before you parse the command and determine the number of child processes required. `for (0..nChildren) {setup pipes; fork;} ..etc`